# I use unity3d Particle System. it performance well on android, but it performance issue on IOS

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, particles

Hi guys，I use unity3d Particle System in my game,  it performance issue on ios. but on android it will be ok.
performs well on android and unity Game preview window,  like this:

[image: pic1]

performance issue on ios , like this :

[image: pic2]

Any comment would be helpful. thanks in advance !

Comment: hi @Fjut.  IT seems strange they would be different.  Please click **EDIT** and paste in some of your CODE so we can see what is going on.  Are you using a **asset store package, or other library**.  If so, click EDIT on your question and explain which one you are using. Include links.

Comment: @Joe Blow thank you for your replay，the issue is the “circle” . it appear normal on android(first picture), on ios device(second picture) the circle's center has been offset.I have not use any asset store package, or other library. I just add the particle to a gameobject, not on the canvas UI。 any suggestions would be helpful, looking forward to your reply. thank you very much.

Comment: The issue may cause by the NPOT textures, when I use POT textures, everything is OK.